# Is this a separable space?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

We have $X = R^n$ and the discrete metric:

$d(x,y) = 0$, if $x=y$ and $d(x,y) = 1$ in all other cases.

Is this space separable or not? I tried to prove, that the answer for that is no.

Let us have a random $x=(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ vector from $R^n$. If $X$ is separable, then such $q$ exists, that $q=(q_1, q_2, ..., q_n)$ and $d(x_i-q_i) < ε$ for all $i$ in ${1,...n}$

The problem with that is, for example if I choose $ε = 1/3$ , then I can't find such $q$ vector, because in discrete metric, we either have 1 as distance, or 0. If some $q_i$ is not equal to its pair, $x_i$, then $d(x_i-q_i)= 1 < 1/3$ is impossible.

That would mean that all $x_i$ and $q_i$ are equal, which makes $x$ equal to $q$, but that's impossible too.

Is that proving good or what you think? Thanks! :)

Comment: You should replace $|x_i - q_i|$ by $d(x,q)$ and then your argument is fine.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, $d(x,q)$ is 1 not the absolute distance. :)

Comment: I made the replacement, thanks once more!

Comment: It should be $d(x,q)$ and not $d(x_i - q_i)$, $d$ is a function of $X \times X$, so it takes two elements from $X$. And not $x_i - q_i$ which is just a real number.

Comment: Oh, and you need to mention that $R^n$ is uncountable.

Answer (score 0):

A short topological proof is to show that in the discrete metric, every subset is closed. This means that the closure of a countable set is the same set, and in particular is countable. But $\mathbb{R}^n$ is uncountable.

A similar proof based on sequences notes that if we have a sequence $x_n$ such that a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ converges to some $x$, then actually $x$ is one of the $x_n$, based on your argument. So there can only be countably many limit points again.

Answer (score 0):

No suppose it has a countable dense set say $D$ then $\overline D=X$; but in discrete metric every set is closed so $\overline D=D$